# Duplicates in large MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, myisam

I have a database that has around 15 million rows. The tables are loaded using `LOAD DATA INFILE` every 48h. Each table has an `id` field. I need to detect duplicate rows that have the same `id` in order to replace them.
I tried the following, but the problem is that the database is too big for this query to finish in reasonable time.

`SELECT id FROM table group by id having count(*) >= 2;`

I'm using indexes and the database storage engine is MyISAM.

Is there a way to detect duplicate rows in a database this size? I tried running the above query in a database that has 1 million rows and it finished in 0.008 seconds so I figured that the database size is the problem.

Comment: `having count(*) >= 2`?

Comment: Do you have any other unique identifiers in the table?  Also, 0.008 seconds seems way to short for this type of query, even with an index.

Comment: @GordonLinoff `id` is the unique identifier in the table with 1 million rows, the same goes for the table with 15 million. The problem is sometimes data from files is not correct, and there can be 2 identical `id`.

Comment: @jarlh `>=` doesn't make any difference in speed in this case.

Comment: MyISAM why using a legacy table engine?.. I advice you to switch over to InnoDB which supports multi threading much beter meaning other clients can still select from the table while inserting which MyISAM does not support... Besides a good configureg MySQL server for InnoDB blasts MyISAM out of way performance wise especially when more then one client are involved.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I'm using MyISAM beacause the databse is used for read only and `LOAD DATA INFILE` is much faster in MyISAM then in InnoDB which is important since I'm loading over 15 million rows.

Comment: @Omega jarth means the query operator is wrong, duplicates can also be greater then 3?

Comment: `= 2` will return id's that exist in two copies. `>= 2` will also return id's that exist in even more copies.

Comment: That's correct, thanks!

Comment: Sounds like the 8ms might be coming from the Query cache.  Please don't quote times without first making sure the QC is not involved.

Comment: @RaymondNijland - It may be reasonable to use MyISAM as a "staging" table type.

Comment: @RickJames Why would use MyISAM in "staging" and InnoDB in production? InnoDB works different then MyISAM so you can get (unexpected) application errors like possibly race conditions (because MyISAM table locks everything) foreign key errors and (in some cases) deadlocks.. Besides if you are going to make a "staging", "testing" and "production" environment for application releasing you should make sure that the software (os, programming language version, MySQL version and even the MySQL storage engine) are the same

Comment: @RaymondNijland - By "staging", I meant: (1) load data into staging table; (2) cleans it; normalize columns; etc; (3) copy whatever is needed to InnoDB tables; (4) drop it.

Comment: @RickJames copying table of this size would be painfully slow

Answer (score 0):

what you did is ok. I can suggest you to write procedure and split your select query into multiple parts. you can create table and store results inside that table.

When your procedure finishes, you will have the results :)

you can partition your table by date

Answer (score 0):

I just ran a quick test on one of my servers which has ~80 million rows and got a response back for duplicates within 2 minutes by doing the following.

```
SELECT id 
FROM table 
GROUP BY id 
HAVING COUNT(id) > 1;
```

The key difference here is that only counting the id'd column in the having clause allows mysql to make better use of the indexed column.

Secondly, in order to remove duplicates you could select the data from your table and import it into another identical table with the id field as a primary key and making use of the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE syntax within MySQL.

As a general rule I would also avoid using MyISAM without a good reason for it and would prefer to use InnoDB by default for the transaction control etc that you get with InnoDB.

Comment: It turned out that I had some MySQL process running in the background which used a lot of server resources, once I killed it and run the query again it finished running after 0.044s. Also, I'm using MyISAM because I'm loading large files into the database and the database is used for read only, which MyISAM handles faster than InnoDB

Answer (score 0):

Consider `LOAD DATA IGNORE` (or `REPLACE`) you can avoid loading the rows in the first place.  This assumes, of course, that there is some unique key on `id`, perhaps `PRIMARY KEY(id)`?

Keep in mind that, with MyISAM, *any* operation, even a simple `SELECT`, blocks writing to the same table.